# Как добавить в pom.xml информацию о версии Java

Tags: java

Как добавить в pom.xml информацию о версии Java?
В проекте Java 11 используется. Вот так выглядит файл, хотел, чтобы любой, кто юзал мой проект - сразу знал о том, какая Java используется и корректно исполнялась программа. Задача, как мне казалась - простая, но  нигде информации об этом не нашёл.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Task 1</groupId>
    <artifactId>Task 1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>6</source>
                    <target>6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
  <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>ssss</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ......
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    ......
  </properties>
  ......
```

либо

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>11</source>
      <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

подробнее [тут](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)